ANN training in pytorch giving me unchanged lossfunction
i am learning pytorch. when I have run my code in jupyter cell the loss function is remaining unchanged. It should be either raised or get down. why is this happening?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_features=4,h1=8,h2=9,out_features=3):
        #how many layers:
        #intiate the inherrited class of nn.Module
        
        super().__init__()
        #Input layer(4 feature)--> hiddenlayer 1 neural net--->hiddenlayer2 neural net-->output(3 classes of Iris dataset)
        #fully connected layer. I could edit the layers here for example first layer is connected with  h1, h1 is connected with h2 
        # then h2 is connecte with out_Features
        #Alternatively i can use  all values of in_features,hidden layers value and out features  loaded in init parameter
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(in_features,h1)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(h1,h2)
        self.out=nn.Linear(h2,out_features)
        
    #propagate method  here start  foroward propagation  
    def forward(self,x):
        x=F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x=F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x=self.out(x)
        return x
    torch.manual_seed(32)
    model=Model()
    df=pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
    df.tail()
    X=df.drop('target',axis=1).values
    y=df['target'].values
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=33)


    X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train)
    X_test=torch.FloatTensor(X_test)

    y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train)

    y_test=torch.LongTensor(y_test)
    criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)
    epoch=100
    #for tracking loss  lets make it a empty list and then make the loss
    losses=[]
    for i in range(epoch):


   #forward and get a prediction
    y_pred=model.forward(X_train)#passing x_train  to forward function which actually applies features in fully connected neural net and activation function applied on those
    #measuring loss between predicted y, and actual y which is y_train. Using CrossEntropyloss, so we dont need to one hot encoding here
    loss=criterion(y_pred,y_train)
    #append the loss into losses for tracking losses in each epoch completion
    losses.append(loss.item())
    # we print this performance every 10 epoch completion
    if i%10==0:
        print(f'epoch{i} and loss is :{loss}')
    
    #Back propagation
    
    optimizer.zero_grad() #resetting the gradient since it accumulates in every epoch
    #print('Optimizer check',optimizer.zero_grad())
    loss.backward()#adjusting the paramter
   
    optimizer.step# updting the weight and bias

output:
epoch0 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch10 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch20 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch30 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch40 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch50 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch60 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch70 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch80 and loss is :1.1507114171981812
epoch90 and loss is :1.1507114171981812


step is a method of the optimizer, so you need to call it to have the parameters updated by the optimizer (based on the gradients calculated by the loss function when you did loss.backward()):
optimizer.step()  # note the () after optimizer.step

